Wrong numbering in theorems environment
I'm using Beamer. Why Example environment has wrong numbering? It should be Example 1, 2, 3, ... but it's not (see code below). How I can fix this?
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}
First definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
First example.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
Second example
\end{example}

\begin{example}
Third example
\end{example}

\end{frame}

\end{document} 



please show what result you get. I get 1, 2, 3, 4

The post was updated with picture. I want: Definition 1, Example 1, Example 2, Example 3 automatically.

Beamer manual, section "5.1.2  Global Structure", paragraph "Numbered Theorems and Definitions" with presentations discourages numbering theorems altogether and in case of doing so despite the disencouragement advices to number everything consecutively rather than introducing separate numbering for each kind of theorem.
This in turn indicates that in case you let the beamer class define some standard theorem-like-environments like definition or example for you, these environments internally share the same counter.
Thus, if you decide to disobey the good advice given in the beamer manual, you can achieve separate numbering of each kind of theorem by specifying the documentclass-option notheorems for preventing the beamer class defining standard theorem-like environments for you and using \newtheorem for defining theorem-like environments yourself so that they don't share the same counter:
\documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\newtheorem{definition}{\translate{Definition}}
\newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}

% This is in the declaration of beamercolorthemedefault.sty / beamerfontthemedefault.sty:
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=green!50!black}
\AtBeginEnvironment{example}{%
  \normalfont
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{parent=example text}%
  \setbeamerfont{block title}{parent=structure}%
  \setbeamerfont{block body}{shape=\normalshape}%
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{definition}{%
  \normalfont
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{parent=structure}%
  \setbeamerfont{block title}{parent=structure}%
  \setbeamerfont{block body}{shape=\normalshape}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{definition}
First definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
First example.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
Second example
\end{example}

\begin{example}
Third example
\end{example}

\begin{definition}
First definition.
\end{definition}

\end{frame}

\end{document} 



Many thanks. How I can get Example 1, Example 2 and Example 3 in green and nonitalic?

@Carlos I did some edits.Sorry for not noticing the issue myself. In case somebody more versed in using the beamer class provides a better answer feel free to unaccept my answer and accept hers/his.

It's perfect! With thanks.
